# Dynamically redirect the stdout of a child on Windows

Tags: windows, perl

I've noticed a couple other questions about handling this, but all seem to suffer from:

- Not working on windows
- requiring the child to finish before retrieving output

What I would like to do is call a program (eg. tshark.exe) and process its output while it runs.

To date I have tried:

- Backticks
- Run3
- Proc::Reliable

all without any success.  I could spend all day trying and failing to find a module which helps me with this (ie. I have spent all day), but I figured it might be better if I just asked if anyone knew of one.

Comment: Make sure the target program is flushing its stdout appropriately (and is actually sending stuff to stdout). There may be some magic incantation to control buffering from the outside, I know not what it may be. If tshark.exe does some funny things it may be confused and decided there is no stdout connected, etc. Does running through cmd.exe /k have any effect?

Comment: Since I'm not writing the target program there isn't a lot of control I have there.  I can confirm it is writing to STDOUT and that is being displayed when I run from cmd.exe.  I imagine the output must be flushed at some point, but I can't get any of these methods to display it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a module. Just learn about the pipe forms of the `open` command -- these work just fine on Windows.

```
my $pid = open (my $cmd_handle, "tshark.exe @options |");
# on success, $pid holds process identifier of the external command.

while (<$cmd_handle>) {
    # sets $_ to next line of output.
    # Will block until a line of output is ready.
    # Is  undef  when the command is complete.

    ... process $_ ...
}
close $cmd_handle;   # waits for command to complete if it hasn't completed yet
```

Comment: Preferred "modern" incantation is `open my $handle, '-|', $command`. With pipes I sometimes get confused when to use `-|` and when to use `|-`.

Comment: You have no idea how much stress you relieved with this answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `IPC::Run`.   `IPC::Open2` and `IPC::Open3` might meet your needs too.

Good luck!